# How to convert "0" to "00" in vedtor in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
x <- c(0, 25, 0, 75, 50, 50, 0)
```

I would like to convert it so the 0's and only the zeroes are double, as so:

```
x <- c(00, 25, 00, 75, 50, 50, 00)
```

Anyone have a neat idea how to do this?

Comment: For numerics, `00` is just `0`. If you want to *display* `"0"` as `"00"` you need to convert a `numeric` vector to a `character` vector. For example, `sprintf("%02i", x)` converts `x` to a `character` vector with a leading zero, giving `"00" "25" "00" "75" "50" "50" "00"`.

Answer (score 1):

```r
x <- c(0, 25, 0, 75, 50, 50, 0)
sprintf('%02.0f', x)
sprintf('%.2d', x)
sprintf('%02i', x)
```

Will all yield identical output

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a format, but you can do this:

```
sprintf("%.2d", x)

# [1] "00" "25" "00" "75" "50" "50" "00"
```

However they will be in character format.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_pad`

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(x, pad = '0', width = 2)
[1] "00" "25" "00" "75" "50" "50" "00"
```